# Problems with overloading operator []

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading, operators

I've written the following code and run into a problem with overloading operator [].
Here's the code for testmain.cpp:

```
#include"test.hpp"

int main()
{
    C tab = C(15);
    bool b = tab[2];
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the header file test.hpp:

```
#ifndef _test_
#define _test_
class C
{
    friend class ref;
    int s;
public:
    class ref
    {
    public:
        bool v;
        ref();
        ref(bool x);
        ref& operator = (ref a);
        ref& operator = (bool x);
    };
    C();
    C(int a);
    bool operator[] (int i) const ;
    ref operator[] (int i);
};
#endif ///_test_
```

When I attempt to compile the code, I get the following error:

```
testmain.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testmain.cpp:6:16: error: cannot convert ‘C::ref’ to ‘bool’ in initialization
```

Looks like the compiler automatically assumes that my indexing operator[] will always return an object of type ref and ignores the operator[] that returns boolean type variable.
Is it possible to fix the code so that the compiler "knows" when to use appropriate overloaded operator[]?

Comment: The compiler tries to work out which function to call based entirely on `tab[2]`. It doesn't look at the `bool b =` part until afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload returning `bool` is `const`, so will only be used when applied to a constant `C` object. Yours is not `const`, so the non-`const` overload is chosen.

One solution is to make `ref` implicitly convertible to `bool`:

```
operator bool() const {return v;}
```

so that you can read a `bool` value in the same way using either overload.

Answer (score 2):

You have two implementations of `operator[]`...one for `const` objects and one for non-const objects.  Your main has a non-const instance of C, so it's invoking the non-const operator, which returns a `ref`.